# OpenGL rendering (only real-time)?

Tags: c++, opengl

I understand that you usually create complex 3D models in Blender or some other 3D modelling software and export it afterwords as .obj. This .obj file gets parsed into your program and openGL will render it. This as far as I understand real-time rendering.

Now I was wondering if there is something like pre-rendered objects. I'm a little bit confused because there are so many articles/videos about real-time rendering but I haven't found any information about none real-time rendering. Does something like this exists or not? The only thing which would come into my mind as none real-time rendering would be a video.

I guess this is pretty much a yes or no question :) but if it exists maybe someone could point me to some websites with explanations.

Comment: You answered it yourself.  It's a video.  Real-time isn't a technique as such.  It just means "with a time constraint".  People misuse the phrase quite a lot I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Real-time rendering" means that the frames are being generated as fast as they can be displayed. "Non-real-time rendering", or "offline rendering" means generating frames one at a time, taking as much time as necessary to achieve the desired image quality, and then later assembling them into a movie. Video at the quality of video games can be rendered in real time; something as elaborate as a Pixar movie, though, has to be done in offline mode. Individual frames can still take hours of rendering time!

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you mean by "prerendered objects", however there are things called VBOs and Vertex Arrays that store the object's geometry in VRAM so as to not have to load it into the rendering pipeline using `glVertex3f()` or similar every frame. This is called Immediate Mode.

VBOs and Vertex arrays are used instead of immediate mode because they're *far* faster than calling the graphics driver to load data into VRAM for every vertex because they are kept in VRAM, which is faster than normal RAM, ready to be booted into the render pipeline.

The page [here](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html) may help, too.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing stopping you from rendering to an [off-screen frame-buffer (i.e., an FBO)](http://oss.sgi.com/projects/ogl-sample/registry/EXT/framebuffer_object.txt) and then saving that to disk rather than displaying it to the screen.  For instance, that's how GPGPU techniques used to work before the advent of CUDA, OpenCL, etc. ... You would load your data as an unfiltered floating point texture, perform your calculation using pixel-shaders on the FBO, and then save the results back to disk.

In the link I posted above, it states in the overview:

> This extension defines a simple interface for drawing to rendering
>       destinations other than the buffers provided to the GL by the
>       window-system.

It then goes on to state,

> By allowing the use of a framebuffer-attachable image as a rendering
>       destination, this extension enables a form of "offscreen" rendering.

So, you would get your "non-real-time" rendering by rendering off-screen some scene that renders slower than 30fps, and then saving those results to some movie file or file-sequence format that can be played back at a later date.